# Increment php variable value every time a function is executed

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, infinite-scroll

I´m sending a formula which is retrieving data through PHP from a MySQL DB. I want to collect the data step by step, by scrolling, a kind of "infinite scrolling" implementation written in Javascript. It´s working fine, except for the fact that I can not find the way to increment the value of the variable that specify which row to start from retrieving data, every time that I call the PHP function from inside a script in my HTML document.

Below is the index.php code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script-->

    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/copy_code.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/preloader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">       

    <?php
    include("dbconnect.php");
    include("search.php");      
    ?>
</head>


<body>

     <!-- Preloader -->
    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- scroll to top buttom -->
    <a href="#" id="scroll"><span></span></a>



<article>

    <div class="entry_content">


        <FORM method=post action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>'>

              <!-- My FORM -->

        </FORM>


        <div id="load_data"> </div>
        <div id="load_data_message"></div>


    </div>
</article>


</body>
</html>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


 var limit = 10;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 console.log("Limite + Start:")
 console.log(limit);
 console.log(start);


 function load_data(limit, start)
 {
  console.log("Limite & Start");
  console.log(limit);
  console.log(start); 

  var data="<?php  echo search(limit, start);  ?>";


    $('#load_data').append(data);

    if(data == '') /* No data: active, "no data found" */
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
     action = 'active';

    }
    else /* data: active, "Please wait..." */
    {

     $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning'>Please Wait....</button>");
     action = "inactive";
    } 
 }


 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  console.log("Inactiva");
  action = 'active';
  load_data(limit, start);
 }


 $(window).scroll(function(){

  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {   
   action = 'active';
   console.log("Activaaaaaa. Start: ");
   start = start + limit; 
   console.log(start);    
   setTimeout(function(){
   load_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 });


});

</script>
```

The search(limit, start) function is inside a search.php file and it is retrieving the values in this way:

```
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE $conditions LIMIT $start, $limit");


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
     echo [...]
}
```

I want to increment this $start variable every time I call the load_data(limit, start) function from index.php.

I tried creating cookies (didn´t work because I can not get the new cookies values before refreshing), creating a static php variable inside the search function and incrementing its value (didn´t work, I do not know why), passing a variable through the form and incrementing its value,... but nothing worked.

Comment: What is not working with passing the variable through the form?

Comment: You don't need to mangle with cookies directly if you use session variables of PHP

Comment: If you are using ajax you can do the increment in the callback

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Passing the variable through the form is working, but I can not increment its value calling again the function.

Comment: how are you hoping to trigger the PHP function? A form will submit and thus refresh the page, PHP runs before the webpage is rendered so you need ajax / fetch

Comment: @RamRaider I´m triggering the search(limit, start).php function every time browser window is scrolled to bottom through the js function load_data(limit, start) in this line of code:    var data="<?php  echo search(limit, start);  ?>";  That works, and I retrieve the data, but always the same ones because the start value does not change. I tried with AJAX and jQuery Form plugin, but after submit the form, the form values were not stored and the next AJAX requests returned an empty result set.

Comment: is your `load_data` function sending an ajax request? I don't use jQuery so I don't know for sure but it doesn't look like it to my untrained eye.

Comment: No, no Ajax request at all in this version. `load_data` function just executes `search.php` function and keeps the returned data.

Comment: I think there might be a small misunderstanding how this works. Without ajax / fetch you cannot `execute search.php` as you are trying to do.... PHP loads and runs before javascript / html.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misunderstanding... the `search.php` file is included at the beginning of the HTML code. `search.php` **contains** a function called `search(limit, start).php`, which is the function that I´m executing in this line of code: `var data="<?php  echo search(limit, start);  ?>";`

Comment: you cannot expect to execute a PHP function without either reloading the entire page ( not what you want for continuous scrolling ) or by sending an ajax request.... it will not work like that. You have misunderstood how it is expected to work I suspect. Look at your source code in the browser - you should see the returned data written into the function `load_data` ~ that will not change without re-executing the PHP function `search`

Comment: To clarify. You wish, when the page scrolls down, to query the database to find the next `page` of results ( based upon `$start` and `$limit` ) and then add new HTML content within the DIV with ID `load_data` - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that´s what I want.

Comment: you cannot do it the way you are attempting without sending a new http request to the PHP server when the page scrolls. You need to send an ajax request - your function, correct me if I am wrong, does NOT send an ajax request - ever. It loads initially with a statically created recordset / html content - and then never changes content as no http request is sent to the php script to fetch new data

Comment: You are right. Now I understand, thank you. The problem is that the subsequent Ajax requests that I should make will not contain the already submitted form values, which are needed to filter the results in MySQL. So I must find out the way of storing those values after every Ajax request.

Comment: have you even looked at what I posted below? In your code you do not make a single ajax call - you do not need to `store` any value after any `ajax` call.... all you need to do is increment the `$start` variable ( in javascript - ajax callback ) ... Try copying all of my answer, save as a new page and run it to see what happens - you should be able to modify it to run your sql query very easily.

Comment: Amazing, it works like a charm. I tested it with a DB query. Tomorrow I will try to embed my form. Thanks a lot @RamRaider

Comment: and then perhaps upvote for the effort?

Comment: Of course, I already did it! But it´s not showing because I´m new in the platform and have not enough reputation. But it´s there.

Comment: ok, good luck with the rest of the coding adventures

Comment: Thank you. And thanks again for your great help.

Comment: you are welcome Amy, I am glad that you finally found the solution.

Comment: Hi @RamRaider... as soon as I embed my own form and click "Send" to submit my values, the screen shows just the first bunch of records and the program stops executing, no more records are loaded when scrolling, and even the form does not load again. I looks like it just executes the PHP script on top and stops loading the HTML code. Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned you could implement the increment of the variable in javascript so put together a simple ajax based infinite scroll system. There is no database query for simplicity but the main logic is there

In order to call any PHP function after the page has loaded you need to send an HTTP request to some script ( or same page ) using either `XMLHttpRequest` ( aka Ajax ) or the newer `fetch` api and use the callback function to append the response in some way.

In the above there is no ajax being used so the initial page loads with a static Javascript variable being written by PHP ( `var data="<?php  echo search(limit, start);  ?>";` ) - once that set of results has been consumed by the javascript function there is no means to fetch the next set of records as it stands. To use a standard form `submit` would not work so I don't see the point, in the above code.

As all you need to do is use the `$start` variable to alter the results returned by the query there is no need for any session or cookie storage - simply let javascript increment the relevant counter.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();


        $page=!empty( $_POST['page'] ) ? $_POST['page'] : 10;
        $limit=!empty( $_POST['limit'] ) ? $_POST['limit'] : 10;


        /* 
            call / query database to fetch the next portion of results.
            Here it is simply emulating the return of data
        */
        for( $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){
            $sql=sprintf('select * from `table` order by id limit %d,%d', $page, $limit);
            printf( '<div>Record #%d from %s</div>', $i+1, $sql );
        }

        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Infinite scroller</title>
        <script>
            const setruntime=function( callback ){
                return document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback );
            }

            const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.send( params );
            };

            const initialise=function(){
                var page=limit=10;
                var status=true;

                const scrollhandler=function(e){
                    if( ( window.innerHeight + window.scrollY ) >= document.body.offsetHeight ){
                        const url=location.href;
                        const payload={
                            'action':'scroll',
                            'page':page,
                            'limit':limit
                        };
                        const callback=function(r){
                            /* process and add response data somehow... */
                            let form = document.forms.geronimo;
                                form.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', r )

                            /* increment the page variable for the NEXT request */
                            page += limit;
                            /* once again set status to true to permit new ajax request */
                            status=true;
                        };

                        /* prepare the querystring for the request */
                        let params=Object.keys( payload ).map( k=>{
                            return [k,payload[k]].join('=')
                        }).join('&');

                        /* send the request */
                        if( status ) ajax( url, params, callback );
                        status=false;
                    }
                }
                document.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollhandler );
            };
            setruntime( initialise );
        </script>
        <style>
            body,body *{font-family:fantasy}
            div{width:50%;float:none;margin:5rem auto;padding:3rem;border:1px dashed rgba(1,1,1,0.1);background-color:rgba(255,253,225,1)}
            div:nth-child(even){background-color:rgba(255,243,243,1)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='geronimo' method='post'>
            <?php
                /* display the first X records, SCROLL to fetch subsequent X + PAGE records... */
                for( $i=1; $i < 10; $i++ )printf( '<div>%d</div>', $i );
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```